# Fade In Raster with PaperJS

Tags: paperjs

How to fade in / fade out a Raster (image) with PaperJS ? Currently I'm using the following clumsy function to handle 1 raster (codes are simplified):

```
var img = new Raster('test.jpg');
img.opacity = 0;

function onFrame() {
  if(img.opacity < 1) {
    img.opacity += 0.1;
  }
}
```

Is there a faster way to do so?

The ultimate aim is to achieve:

- Fade In > Hold 3 seconds > Fade Out

Comment: faster in terms of what?

Comment: Faster in terms of code simplicity , e.g. use 1 `fadeIn()` function to achieve the same thing.

Comment: There's [this attempt](https://github.com/Eartz/animatePaper.js) at an animation lib for paper.js - I'm not sure if a  fadeIn()  is included but there's some interesting examples

Comment: this plugin seems to work great, as it supports animate of `opacity`. will try soon. thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

There's [this attempt](https://github.com/Eartz/animatePaper.js) at an animation lib for Paper.js.

---

As a side note it would be nice if you kept it's creator updated with bugs or any recommendations in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paperjs/JxEbn94yVYw)